# How can I add a middleware logger to my bot?

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I tried to add telemetry services following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), but I looked at my logs in azure and I didn't see user messages. How can I add a middleware that can save user's conversations?

What I'm trying to do is to capture the messages that LUIS and QnA could not find an answer for. So we want to log these so we can improve our bot in the future.

I know LUIS has this feature already in luis.ai, but we want to add more information than what LUIS captures.

Comment: Are you wanting to add telemetry or save user conversations? Adding telemetry does not save user messages/conversations. Rather, it tracks meta data like types of activities (e.g. messages, events, etc.), # of QnA messages that returned failed responses, and other used features.

Comment: I want to save user conversations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a custom implementation for storing user conversations. I have used Azure Table in one of my implementations to store the conversation. The table structure will have the conversation id + user id as the unique key and then storing the conversation in json format in the table. The conversation data is updated by intercepting every message sent to and from the bot. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) MSDN article for a reference implementation.